# CodeIgniter stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ssl

I have two CodeIgniter installs running on one domain. A beta and a public one. On the beta I am sending my e-mails using PHPMailer. I am sending the e-mails through SMTP with a Office365 account.

On the beta the e-mails do send; on the public one (exact same code, config) I get this error:

```
ERROR - 2016-06-16 12:38:08 --> Severity: Warning --> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout /home/acties/domains/acties.sundays.nl/private_html/system/libraries/Email.php 2002
```

I am clueless.